# How do I access orange on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: orange

I have used pip to install orange and the installation seemed fine.  There was not Orange icon on my ubuntu 16.04 desktop and tried orange3 in the command line, it didn't work, and tried python3 -m orange and python3 -m orange 3 and neither worked as well.

How can I use orange?

Answer (score 2):

From the [Orange3 Pypi documentation](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Orange3) :

> To start Orange GUI from the command line, assuming it was successfully installed, run:
>
> ```
> orange-canvas # or python3 -m Orange.canvas
> ```

Comment: I removed orange and tried to reinstall using pip and got the following:

Comment: I think you forgot to paste your error in your comment.

Comment: I found I was having problems with packages in general and a got a system error, so I had to rebuild my os.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should fire up a python console and try `import orange`.

If it doesn't give you any errors then the installation succeeded.

For the GUI, try something like:`python /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Orange/OrangeCanvas/orngCanvas.pyw` (change python version)

Answer (score 0):

Using Anaconda

If you are using python provided by Anaconda distribution, you are almost ready to go.
Add conda-forge to the list of channels you can install packages from

conda config --add channels conda-forge

and install packages

conda install orange3
conda install -c defaults pyqt=5 qt

Now create the conda environment named orange3

conda create python=3 orange3 --name orange3

Activate the environment, run orange3 and finally deactivate it

conda activate orange3
python3 -m Orange.canvas
conda deactivate

Moreover, you probably have Anaconda Navigator (the graphical interface to conda) in anaconda3 . Why not using it ?

cd home/anaconda3/bin
./anaconda-navigator

Now the graphical interface to conda starts, then choose the orange3 environment, and run orange3